# Need help with creation of an example

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

I've been struggling for days now and I cannot come up with an example of a function $f(x)$ that satisfies the following:

1. $|f(x)−f(y)| < |x−y|$ for any $x, y ∈ R$

AND

2. equation $f(x) = x$ does not have any solutions.

Do you have a grasp as to how construct such examples? Thank you!

Comment: Strict inequality is impossible if $x=y$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Look for functions that have $|f'(x)| < 1$ (this follows from MVT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$
f(x) = x + \pi/2 - \arctan x 
$$
Since $\arctan x < \pi/2$ for all $x$, we have $f(x)>x$ for all $x$. Furthermore, you can show $0<f’(x)<1$ for all $x$, which implies $|f(x)-f(y)|<|x-y|$ for all $x\neq y$, via MVT.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ works, if you restrict your domain to $[1,\infty)$.

It's worth noting that constructing an example from $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ may be a bit difficult. This is because of the [Banach Fixed Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) (which I imagine you are already thinking about.) The theorem says that if $f$ is a contraction mapping, then $f$ has a fixed point. In other words, if there exists a $k$ with $0\leq k<1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)| < k|x-y|$, then the equation $f(x)=x$ has a solution (in fact, exactly one.)
In general, the slightly weaker condition $|f(x)-f(y)| < |x-y|$ for $x\neq y$ (your condition 1.) is not enough to guarantee the existence of such a fixed point.
So, in order to construct your example, you must find a function such that no such $k$ exists, but your condition 1. is still satisfied. This implies that such a function must have $$\sup_{x,y\in \mathbb{R}}\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=1.$$

Additionally, if $f:X\to X$ satisfies your condition 1. where $X$ is compact, then condition 1 actually *is* enough to guarantee the existence of a fixed point. So if a function $f$ with the properties you seek exists, it cannot map any compact set into itself.
So if such a function exists, there are some pretty stringent criteria it must satisfy.